# Tree view drag and drop using Jquery and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, treeview

I have to create the tree view with drag and drop,once i did the drag it will need to change in DB level.for your better understanding  go through with this link.

**URL :** http://demos.telerik.com/php-ui/treeview/dragdrop

do you have any idea and solution kindly share with me.

Comment: You need to create database to save data, update based on your need using PHP Ajax.

Comment: yes i know that, i want some reference to do that